# Bootstrap WYSIWYG: insert char c at index i

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, bootstrap-wysiwyg

I need some help regarding Bootstrap WYSIWYG. From my point of view, the content needs to be a string and I want to have full control of what is happening.

I want to use `editorInsert(c, i)` which does the insertion of the character `c` at the index `i`. Here is a code to start I guess.

```
$('#editor').wysiwyg().on('keypress', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

If you could make it work with a char or a string, it would be really nice.

Thanks.